# Security message for Internet explorer because of background-url style

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am on a https site and I get a security popup message, "You have mixed content, non-secure items on a secure page".  It looks like removing the inline style:  `background-image:url('../images/img.png')`   fixes the problem.  Does anyone know why?

```
<div style="background-image:url('../images/img.png')" />
```

With Internet Explorer, I wonder if the 'background-image:url' uses a different download mechanism.

This is IE7-8.

Here is a related bug from Microsoft but I still can't find any more details on what is wrong with IE.
Reference:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925014

Comment: Weird. Can you show the CSS code (or element markup) in question?

Comment: There is no CSS.  It is a style attribute.  I think it is an IE bug.

Comment: Any chance of a live example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like even though you're using HTTPS to view the page, IE is trying to load the image referenced in the CSS over an HTTP connection regardless of what the page is actually using (hence the mixing of secure and unsecure content).

Try changing the reference in the CSS to an absolute reference using HTTPS:

```
background-image:url('https://site.com/images/img.png');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer; the issue was fixed in IE9. See the comments here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx for discussion.

Comment: I liked the comment, choosing this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This because the background image come from an HTTP request and not HTTPS so that's why is called mixed content.

To solve this quickly just move the background image inside the HTTPS location webserver

```
background-image:url('https://yourdomain../images/img.png')
```

Comment: No, it is an IE bug.  The image is requested as https.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just a bit ago. I solved it by switching my syntax from this:

```
body{
  background:#600 url('webpage_back.png') fixed no-repeat top center;
}
```

to this:

```
body{
  background:#600 url('webpage_back.png') no-repeat fixed center top;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea, I am posting the IE bug.